# When I compile C# program in Rider I get a "dotnet crashed" message in Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, rider

When I compile CSharp programm in Rider and I get an error I get "dotnet crashed" message in Mac OS X.
.NET Core version is 3.1

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGBF.png)

https://dumpz.org/b7gGDdW7y6Ba - error message by Mac OS X

Comment: Please post the exact error message you receive. Does this happen with any program or one specific? Are you able to post a minimal example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Okay but It will be illogically to compile always from command line.

Comment: I hope it wasn't sarcasm because it looks like. @BWA

Comment: I already tried all basic stuff like reload the computer or Rider.

Comment: @germi I added the screenshot of the Mac OS's message about dotnet

Comment: Ok, and command line compilation works? Maybe something with dotnet, not with Rider.

Comment: @BWA yes the command line compilation doesn't crash dotnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
I just removed all .NET libraries (Mono too) from Mac OS and then installed them from Rider.